# What does the warning "npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory" mean?

Tags: json, node.js

While installing code from Github using NPM on my Mac, I got the following error messages:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/wayneenter/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/wayneenter/package.json'
npm WARN wayneenter No description
npm WARN wayneenter No repository field.
npm WARN wayneenter No README data
npm WARN wayneenter No license field.

node check 
nmp check 
git check
```

What do these warnings mean, and what steps can be taken to resolve them?

Comment: Not a good question. Read the [how to ask good question on stackOverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

ENOENT is short for "Error, No Entry" - as explained in this question [npm install jquery error / saveError ENOENT / Invalid dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359360/npm-install-jquery-error-saveerror-enoent-invalid-dependency#44359436)

This means that NPM was looking for the file '/Users/wayneenter/package.json' and could not find it. These warnings inform you that the package 'wayneenter' is lacking a package file - which NPM uses to manage dependencies for the package.

The other warnings describe data which NPM would have expected to find in this missing file.